# Solidify Modifier doesn't work

Tags: modeling, modifiers, export, cloth-simulation

I am pretty new to Blender but with tutorials I came at least this far.

I made a mesh blanket over a mesh bench. I used cloth simulation to make the blanket a nice fit and at the frame I liked I used *Apply* under the *Moderfiers* tab in *Properties* ,to make the cloth a mesh.

This is the front of the blanket and then the back with *Solidify* applied:

[image: Front]

[image: Back]

But when I try to upload it into my virtual world, the back is still blank:

[image: inworld]

Comment: To me, it looks like you've exported the mesh without applying the solidify modifier before the export (or checking some export option that does it automatically).

Comment: I didn't export it without the solidify and i wouldn't know about any export options to check

Comment: There is also potentially a problem with the normals already in Blender. Try enabling "Backface Culling" in the [3D view properties --> Shading --> Backface Culling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WmFkt.png) to see if that hides it as well.

Comment: If you aren't uploading as a .blend file, you will see [something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wG6Gw.png) in the export settings.

Comment: I have to export it as a collada to make it work in Second Life. I did look in Blackface Culling and it shows blank without solidify and filled with solidify like the pictures.

Comment: @Siara So did you check the box [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/itPHZ.png)?

Comment: OMG now you see what a noob i am. That was unchecked. Thank you so much! That was the trick :)

Comment: The mesh was seen-through because it hasn't had any thickness. As normals by definition can point only one side those faces aren't seen from another side in the engines which can't do that (e.g. game engines). As Solidify is Blender modifier game engine isn't aware of it, you have to apply the modiifier to make geometry real

Answer (score 2):

You must either apply the modifier manually or enable "Apply modifiers" in the export settings for whatever file type you are exporting to. For Collada, the setting is here:

[image]